# PHP: Mail not sent

Tags: php

I am trying on the following code but it keeps saying `Mail not sent`. How do I find the real issue? Code given below:

```
    $full_name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['full_name']));
    $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
    $phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));
    $message = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['message']));

$to = "mail@example.com";


$subject = $full_name . ' is interested to have a business discussion with you';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
//    $headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h3>Full Name: </h3>: ' . $full_name . '<br>';
$message .= '<h3>Phone: </h3>: ' . $phone . '<br>';
$message .= '<h3>Message: </h3>: ' . $message . '<br><br>=======================<br>';
$message .= '<h3>IP Address: </h3>: ' . $ip . '<br>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
}else{
    echo " Mail Not Sent";
}
```

Comment: where is $to variable's value?

Comment: where is your `$to` and also where did you assign the variable `$full_name`

Comment: @StreetCoder Question updated

Comment: that is going to send it to the email address "mail@example.com" which may not be an actual email address it can send to, causing the fail. Try putting in a real email address. Also is this on a live server or in a local server which needs to be specifically configured to send email

Comment: I am testing it on live server as I know I don't have a local setup. Could it be some issue at hosting end? Also, I deliberately put a fake email id here.

Comment: Try to use some simple SMTP mail sending procedure. I think that may work.

Comment: did you loacte where is the error?

Comment: @sradha I wish i knew how to do it

Comment: I have checked myself that email is sent. So, please check the variable you are getting from `post` method and the variable `$ip`

Comment: make sure your mail function is enabled by server

Comment: Had it been disable I'd have got message. I tried a simple one and got no response. Seems hosting issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this code hope this helpful.

```html
<?php
//print_r($_POST);

//$fname = $_POST['fname'];
//$lname = $_POST['lname'];
//$email = $_POST['email'];
//$message = $_POST['message']; 


if(isset($_POST['fname']) && $_POST['fname'] != ''){
     $fname = $_POST['fname'];
}
if(isset($_POST['lname']) && $_POST['lname'] != ''){
     $lname = $_POST['lname'];//phone number
}
if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''){
     $email = $_POST['email'];
}

if(isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != ''){
     $com = $_POST['message'];
}

$to  = 'noreply@noreply.com';

$subject = 'Site Visiter.';

// message
$message = sprintf("Site visiter details: <br>Name:- %s <br> Phone:- %s <br> Email:- %s<br> Message:- %s",$fname,$lname,$email,$com);

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <nb158f@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: mysite.com <admin@site.com>' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: divakar.k@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
$flag = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo '<script>alert("Mail Sent :");</script>';
echo '<script>window.location.href="index.php";</script>';
```